# Center aligning of title in action bar of activity and fragments

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My HomeActivity consists of Sliding Menu where each option in Sliding Menu opens a new Fragment with different title. I want that title in action bar of fragments and activity appear in center.I tried using custom layout for fragment-

```
 final ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();

        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
       // actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        ab.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

actionbar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="title"

        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This aligns the title in center but the sliding menu disappears.I want that all my fragments display title in center of action bar and sliding menu should not vanish.Here is my code for manifest,styles.xml,activity and one of the fragment and also xml file for Home Activity..

Manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.slidingmenu.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TabText</item>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:background">#12ABEE</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>
 <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

    </style>
```

HomeActivity

```
public class Home extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle, mTitle;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private String mName, mProfileimage;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private ImageView profileImageView;

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = 40;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slidermenu);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_view);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        nameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        profileImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_profile_image);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Home.this);

        mName = app_preferences.getString("name", "null");
        mProfileimage = app_preferences.getString("profileimage", "null");

        nameTextView.setText(mName);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(mProfileimage);
            Bitmap lProfileBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            lProfileBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(lProfileBitmap);
            BitmapDrawable lProfileDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(lProfileBitmap);
            profileImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(lProfileDrawable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("error in image", e.toString());
        }
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[11], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(11, -1)));

        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(this.linearLayout);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HF();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NF();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FD();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new FDFD();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new VideosFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new DG();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new DSF();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new FDSF();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new DFSD();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new DFSF();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(this.linearLayout);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

}
```

VideosFragment

```
public class VideosFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    private int countClick;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    private String[] tabs = {"All Teams Videos", "Player Videos", "My Team Videos"};

    public VideosFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos, container, false);

        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search2:

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(myContext, LS.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

}
```

slidermenu.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bgmenu"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_profile_background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profileblock">

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/drawer_profile_background"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawer_profile_background"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settingicon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drawer_profile_background"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawer_profile_background"
                android:background="@drawable/settings" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/drawer_profile_background"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"></TextView>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/menuselector" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `TextView` of your custom `ActionBar` layout to center the text.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Also, to explain, when you set `gravity="center"` that just centers the text in the `TextView` layout.

Next, your icon hides because your custom layout overlaps the icon for the navigation drawer (siding menu). To fix this, the easiest way is to set a margin for your entire layout (in your case, the relative layout of your custom actionbar layout). I think 30dp should be enough to cover all screen sizes.

```
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
```

Comment: using custom actionbar layout does centre the title but sliding menu doesn't appear...I want that all my fragments display title in center of action bar and sliding menu should not vanish.

Comment: The sliding menu or just the icon?

Comment: i don't see the icon of sliding menu..if just the icon disappears then what i have to do to make it appear?or where i have gone wrong?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. That should solve your issue.

Comment: should i use android:layout_marginRight="30dp" in custom layout?

Comment: yes, in your the relative layout of your custom layout